# Über den Ausdruck "in der Ehre kränken"

Tags: phrase

In einem im Jahr 1878 erschienenen Wörterbuch stehen unter *Laster* (aufgrund der Etymologie des Wortes) zwei Ausdrücke, nämlich **die Ehre kränken** und **an der Ehre kränken**. Nachdem ich diese Ausdrücke gegooglelt habe, fand ich heraus, dass der anscheinend korrekter Ausdruck eigentlich **in der Ehre kränken** ist. Mit *korrekt* bezeichne ich in diesem Fall den Ausdruck, den heutzutage am meisten benutzt wird. Stimmt das oder sind manche der Obigen sogar austauschbar beziehungsweise können heute noch verwendet werden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"An der Ehre kränken" würde nicht sonderlich falsch klingen, aber keiner würde es in dieser alten Variante ausdrücken. Manchmal passiert es eventuell, dass Leute aus Ungenauigkeit die Phrase abändern, was dann beim Gegenüber einen kurzen Gedanken "hier stimmt etwas nicht" erzeugt.

"In der Ehre kränken" oder "die Ehre kränken" wird formelhaft unverändert verwendet, wobei Ersteres für mich etwas hochgestochener klingt und der Ausdruck generell schon ziemlich gewählt formuliert ist.

gültige Beispiele:

> Seine Ehre wurde gekränkt.
>   Er wurde in seiner Ehre gekränkt.

Comment: Herzlichen Dank.